# Question regarding Model updating in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am following an example and in that:-

```
<input type='text' ng-model='name'>   
<p> Hello {{callingName()}} </p>
<p> Hello {{helloWorld()}} </p> //I added this later, not a part of the example.
```

in .js

```
$scope.name = '';
$scope.callingName = function(){
        return $filter('lowercase')($scope.name);
}
```

I see the callingName is constantly(2 way binding taking place) called once I start changing the model property name via *input box*.

I tried adding my own function.

```
 $scope.helloWorld = function(){
 var x = $scope.name;
 return  "Hello World" + x;
}
```

Now when **$scope.name** is being changed again, shouldn't `helloWorld()` be also called again and again? But it doesn't? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`helloWorld` is not used in the HTML template, hence there is no need to call it when other values changes.

AngularJS has no was of knowing that you are using `$scope.name`: it is calling all methods which are used in the template.

If you need to call a particular function when a scope value changes, you can do it by using `$scope.$watch` in your controller.

You seem to be learning AngularJS, which is surprising in 2021!
That's OK to maintain old projects, but don't use it for anything new!

Comment: `callingName()` is getting called, because you added `<p> Hello {{callingName()}} </p>` in the HTML template

Comment: I did the same with helloWorld()!

Comment: Can you setup a plunker/jsfiddle? (or show the code in a unified snippet so that it can be checked)

Comment: actually both are being called
https://jsfiddle.net/wbzh187t/3/

Comment: Then is it fixed? You can delete the question in that case (as it is unlikely to be useful for someone else)

Comment: Not seeing the delete option.

Comment: Maybe you can delete your answer.?